# MacOS on Proxmox Installation

Tags: bash, mac-osx, proxmox

I found a great tutorial how to install a MacOS on Proxmox VM which I've followed until I reached the installer step which is not allowing me to contain giving an error message "Installer Can Continue Requires Internet Connection".

I have bash terminal access thus I used `ifconfig` to setup the network adding IP, DNS, Gateway etc. And then

```
echo -e "nameserver 8.8.8.8\nnameserver 8.8.4.4" > /etc/resolv.conf
```

To setup DNS giving internet access to the Installer. However the internet is working on IP level but not on the Hostname level.

When pinging `8.8.8.8` I get response result but when pinging `google.com`it returns error:

```
ping: cannot resolve google.com: Unknown host
```

MAc Installer is ignoring the resolv.conf to set a DNS.

Any solution please? Note I'm in Bash Terminal so it's a read-only system with limited functions and parameters.

Mac being installed on Proxmox 5.x using Clover.ISO

Comment: did you set default gateway?

Comment: Yes I did `route add default x.x.x.x` in Mac you don't need to add `gw` after default. It's set but still the issue not resolved.